# LinearLayout within Recyclerview, within another LinearLayout within another RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-recyclerview

Good morning, I have a problem trying to link a Recyclerview with another Recyclerview, I mean one within others, the first recyclerview is in my activity, which in turn is filler for a second recyclerview, which is in a LinearLayout, since Once that recyclerview is filled by another layout that has an ImageView and a TextView, the problem is that I can not use the two recycler view since the app stops, but if I use the layout separately if they work in the same way, I know if I explain, I have 3 layouts which are:

The problem is that I can not use both recycler view since the app stops, but if I use the layout separately if they work in the same way, I do not know if I explain myself, I have 3 layouts, the one in the activity that contains a recyclerview, the container of the elements that contains the second recyclerview and a texview, and finally the layout portraitLayout that contains an imageView and a texView, if I only use the layout of the activity, the second one is rendered well but without any image, and if I remove the layout of the activity and leave the second with the third this is rendered with their respective images.

[image]

I have 2 adapters which are:

AdapterPortrait:

```
`public class Adapter_Portrait extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Portrait.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Portrait> portraits;
    private int layout;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private Context context;


    public Adapter_Portrait(List<Portrait> portraits, int layout, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.portraits = portraits;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(this.layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder(v);
        context=parent.getContext();
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(portraits.get(position),this.listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return portraits.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePortrait);
            this.textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNamePortrait);

        }


        public void bind(final Portrait portrait, final OnItemClickListener listener){
            this.textView.setText(portrait.getName_portrait());
            Picasso.with(context).load(portrait.getImagePortrait()).fit().into(imageView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onItemClick(portrait, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(Portrait portrait, int position);
    }
}`
```

AdapterList_Pieces:

```
`public class AdapterList_Pieces extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterList_Pieces.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Artist> artists;
    private int layout;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private Context context;

    public AdapterList_Pieces(List<Artist> artists, int layout, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.artists = artists;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewPieces);
            this.textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPieces);
        }


        public void bind(final Artist artist, final OnItemClickListener listener){
            this.textView.setText(artist.getName_artist());


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onItemClick(artist, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(this.layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder(v);
        context=parent.getContext();
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(artists.get(position),this.listener);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return artists.size();
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(Artist artist, int position);
    }

}`
```

My Activity is:

```
public class PiecesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Artist> artists;
    List<Portrait> portraits;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewPiece;
    RecyclerView.Adapter rAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerPiece;
    RecyclerView.Adapter AdapterPiece;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.portraitcontenetorslayout);

        recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewListPieces);
        recyclerViewPiece= findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewPieces);
        artists= ConsultingInformation.getArtist();
        portraits= ConsultingInformation.getPortrait();
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManagerPiece =   new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        rAdapter= new Adapter_Portrait(portraits,R.layout.portraitlayout, new Adapter_Portrait.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Portrait portrait, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(PiecesActivity.this, "This piece is "+ portraits.get(position).getName_portrait(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        recyclerViewPiece.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewPiece.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerViewPiece.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerPiece);
        recyclerViewPiece.setAdapter(rAdapter);

        AdapterPiece= new AdapterList_Pieces(artists,R.layout.portraitcontenetorslayout, new AdapterList_Pieces.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
                public void onItemClick(Artist artist, int positionArt) {
                    Toast.makeText(PiecesActivity.this, "This list of pieces is "+ artists.get(positionArt).getName_artist(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        });

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(AdapterPiece);

    }



}`
```

I had read that it was not possible to put a list downloadble within another, but i did not get an unstable method for my case that are two list of objects one within another.

My layouts just in case.

PortraitLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePortrait"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNamePortrait"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

portraitcontenetorlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPieces"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#BCBCBC"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:text=" TextView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewPieces"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activitypieces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Obras" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewListPieces"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Never nest scroll elements which scroll in the same direction, it's not going to work. You'll have to change your design instead of trying to get this working.

Comment: Is not there any way possible for this to work, if I integrate my second RecyclerView into a Fragment it could not work?

Comment: you have to change your adapter to bind to two different layout based on item position. in this way you don't need two recyclerview. with just one recyclerview and two item layouts you can get the desired function

Comment: It's not that it wouldn't work because of technical reasons, it wouldn't work because of user interface reasons. If the user makes a scroll gesture, how would the app know what RecyclerView the user wants to scroll? And what gesture do you expect the user to make if he wants to scroll a particular RecyclerView? Depending on what information you want to display you should either make 1 big RecyclerView or make 2 screen with 1 RecyclerView each.